# Is the Marvel Cinematic Universe Earth-199999 or Earth-616?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe

Which earth does the *Marvel Cinematic Universe* belong to? I remember in *Thor: The Dark World*, it was referred to as 616 by Erik Selvig:

[image: Thor: The Dark World screenshot of scene described above]

But I remember lots of sources claiming it to be Earth-199999, even a few stating it to be official, and lots of [fandoms](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-199999) still call it that. But again, Mysterio called it 616, who is not really a reliable narrator.

So who is right? Which earth is the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(Marvel_Comics)#List_of_main_alternate_Earths_and_universes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's “616” or the “Sacred Timeline”, officially.

According to the official book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, the main MCU universe is designated as “616” or the “Sacred Timeline”. In-universe, it is the Time Variance Authority (TVA), via Miss Minutes (both introduced in the *Loki* TV series), that gave these designations to the main MCU universe.

[image: image of the page where the quote below came from]

> INTRODUCTION
>
> Hey Y'all! I'm Miss Minutes, and welcome to the guidebook on the beings and events that make up the universe known as 616, also known as the Sacred Timeline. Here at the Time Variance Authority, our job is to keep tabs and protect the countless timelines that weave together our Multiverse. Some of these have small differences, like altered lunar cycles or events happening at slightly different times, or big ones—like everybody being made out of paint! Now, 616 may be just one thread in this vast Multiverse, but trust me, it's a wild one!

As to how Mysterio learned of the "616" designation, you can check out this question: "[How did Mysterio (Quentin Beck) know about the multiverse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/117503/1006)"

Answer (score 7):

According to the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe (A to Z)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1)*

- **Earth-616** is the "Mainstream reality".

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z Vol.1 #2 (Glossary)*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_2)</sup></sub>

- **Earth-199999** is the universe in which *Iron Man* (and hence the rest of the MCU) takes place.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z Vol.1 #5 (Glossary)*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_5)</sup></sub>

Comment: A link to this book with a quote would be perfect

Comment: It's a physical book .. under copyright .. it may not be possible to link to the quote.

Comment: What about Erik and Mysterio?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Maybe in universe they call it 616, but in other universes it’s 199999?

Comment: @DonielF that make it more weird if true

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't make a note of _which_ OHotMU#5 that was, as apparently there have been multiple releases.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the actual quotes and references. Note that "[Earth Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Prime)" is *our own* reality, not the main comicbook reality.

Answer (score 7):

[*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness) has confirmed that "616" is the designated number for the MCU Prime universe.

> **Christine 2:** *Our universe is 838. And we've designated yours 616.*
>
> **Strange:** *Oh. You guys sure must know a lot about the Multiverse. You got someone going around naming realities.*

Marvel producer Nate Moore, during interviews publicizing the release of *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, [called](https://screenrant.com/marvel-mcu-earth-616-universe-confirmed/amp/) the universe that the films of the MCU takes place in “*the MCU 616 universe*” but this doesn’t appear to be any sort of official statement.

> *"You will not see T'Challa in the MCU 616 Universe. We couldn't do it.
> I will say that when Chad [Boseman] passed, it was a real conversation
> that we had with [Ryan] Coogler about 'what do we do'? And, it was a
> fast conversation. It wasn't weeks, it was minutes of 'we have to
> figure out how to move this franchise on without that character'. I
> think we all feel that so much of T'Challa in the MCU, not in comics,
> is tied to Chadwick's performance, is what he brought to that role
> both on and offscreen, I would argue."*

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel that two independent sources saying the same thing make your argument that it's "unsettled". Are there other sources saying other things?

Comment: @Valorum mostly just the [answer above](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/105791/19842). The quote I linked to was just an off-the-cuff remark made by a producer as part of an unrelated question. If they had been asked specifically about the universe number I'd have given it more credence. But it looks like there's another reference in Loki, so your edit to make it more definitive seems appropriate.