# How did Mysterio (Quentin Beck) know about the multiverse?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider Man: Far From Home*, Mysterio talks to Peter about the multiverse. Although it's a lie, he clearly mentions the universe 616, which is the main marvel universe (anyone who reads the comics or watched the animated TV series knows this).

But we (or those in the cinematic universe) only were presented to multiverse names in the new *Dr. Strange in The Multiverse of Madness*.

Mysterio could've guessed they live in a multiverse, but how could he know that they're living in 616?

He does not have superpowers or an intelligence like Tony, Reed or Banner.

Comment: @iandotkelly It's not a spoiler, Mysterio appears quite prominently in the trailers for *Far From Home*.

Comment: Anyone can make up a number. 616 is am easter egg for MCU fans not actual **knowledge**.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yes, but answer to the question in the title is obvious based on what the audience is led to believe prior to the reveal, the fact that someone would ask it even after watching the movie is a spoiler.

Comment: But he "makes up" a number which is exactly the same number as reported in another universe. Coincidence?

Comment: I thought it was FURY who mentions Earth 616?  I could be wrong about that.

Comment: So he could have just made up a number and gotten lucky. That said, in MoM, it's said that dreams are visions of other multiverses. So it's possible that he had a dream about his 'other self' in another universe and 616 was somehow referenced. I'm just spit-balling though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of universe, this is pretty clearly an example of something that was intended to be an Easter egg to the comic lore, before that aspect later became incorporated into the actual MCU canon. There is no chance that when *Far From Home* came out, the writers intended Beck's comment to be a factual statement about the nature of multiverses.

That said, having seen *Multiverse of Madness*: **why couldn't he have dreamed it?** Dreams are revealed to be visions into alternate universes that even ordinary people have. For all we know, in the 838 universe, the technically brilliant Beck works closely with the Illuminati and is aware of universe 616, which the 616-Beck subconsciously works into his act after a dream.

Answer (score 8):

In [*Ms. Marvel* episode 3](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Destined), we learn that [Dr. Erik Selvig](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Erik_Selvig) has published papers based on his research on inter-dimensional travel.

> **Kamala** (*to Bruno*)**:** You're good at math. Do you know anything about interdimensional travel off the top of your head? Specifically that of the *Noor* dimension? That's N-O-O...
> **Bruno:** Actually, that reminds me of a paper I read. I think it's by Dr. Erik Selvig.

Bruno studying Selvig's papers:
[image: Bruno studying Selvig's papers]

> **Bruno:** So I plugged in the energy signatures from our tests on you and I ran a simulation.
> [...]
> **Bruno:** Seriously, remember the paper I was talking about? Theoretically, it's possible. [...]

It's likely that Beck or someone from his team of former Stark Industries employees (likely the writer, Guterman) has also read Selvig's papers, and crafted Beck's story about the multiverse and the "616" designation based on that. Relevant dialogue from *Spider-Man: Far From Home*:

> **Beck:** To Guterman.
> [...]
> The story you created of a soldier from another Earth named Quentin fighting space monsters in Europe is totally ridiculous and apparently exactly the kind of thing people will believe right now. I mean, everybody bought it.

See this screencap of Dr. Erik Selvig from *Thor: The Dark World* (2013). Notice the information he's written on the blackboard in the background, and that "616 universe" is written on there. This was pre-[Snap](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Snap), years before the events of *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019).

[image: Erik Selvig with "616 universe" written on the blackboard in the background]

Answer (score -2):

To add to what @galacticninja has said the existence of extra-dimensional phenomena was public knowledge by at this time in the MCU, millions of people had seen the wormhole above New York during the Chitari invasion, and the dimensional distortions during Dark World. We also know from Thor that the scientific community had been investigating the concept before then.

So, it's likely that he simply embellished what people already knew.

Comment: "millions of people had seen the wormhole above New York during the Chitari invasion, and the dimensional distortions during Dark World"  — that's not the same thing as other universes (or dimensions) though. The Chitauri were coming through a portal in space from another location in the same universe. I don't remember what the heck was going on in Thor, but I don't think that involved different universes or dimensions either.

Comment: I'm merely stating that the basic concepts were already in the public consciousness. Do you think that the people who say the wormhole knew that it went to another part of Space, or another universe?

Comment: Do you think the people who saw the wormhole thought “oh, that’ll be a portal to parallel universe”? If so, why? Do you think that after it was done, no-one asked Tony Stark what happened? In _Iron Man 2_ had to testify before Congress after one little highway fight!

Comment: I think that it's enough for them to know that portals to somewhere, anywhere exist.

Comment: Cool. Feels like "portal" and "copy of our entire universe where some things are different" are two unrelated concepts.